# Google custom search Map

Tags: search, google-maps

http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/labeledmarker/release/examples/markerhider.html

I want to build the map as displayed in the above link.
It takes data from xml file for display.

My problem is that i have to take data of google search and display the data in map.

so when user click on hotels then hotel will display in map.

Google has develop to find near by location as here

http://www.google.com/uds/solutions/mapsearch/index.html

But it removes the previous search when second search is made.

Means restaurant search will be removed when search for any other location is made.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

The [Google Ajax Search API Local Search](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/local.html) ought to let you do a search for local information and include it in your Maps API app.